# Is it possible to do user impersonification with minio?

Tags: object-storage, minio

I would need to do user impersonation or have some kind of user/group/permissions.

Is it possible with Minio, or shall I implement my own permission system for every access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minio implements AWS S3 APIs. The access key in the case of AWS S3 is not related to any `user/group/permissions` . So, you might have to do that in your application.